# MPI coupling application

Tags: mpi, physics, coupling

I am working in a parallel program for simulating a couple physics problem  where I have to create different communicators and inter-communicators. Let's say I have a program A and program B. I can have many processors executing A and B. The processes of B are going to be joined into small communicators where A will be in only one.

> A1 --- B1 --- B2 --- B3
>
> |
>
> A2 --- B4
>
> |
>
> A3 --- B5 --- B6 --- B7

Here

1. A1, A2, A3 belong to comm_1
2. B1, B2, B3        to comm_2
3. B4                to comm_3
4. B5, B6, B7        to comm_4

This arrange and the number of process can vary for A and B depending on the problem. My idea is to read from an input this connectivity structure and according to it perform the splits of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. The programs will be executed by:

```
mpirun -np np1 prog_1 : -np np2 prog_2
```

is this a valid procedure ? there exist a simpler way of doing this (without using `MPI_Spawn` and `MPI_Comm_connect` I mean to lunch all process at the same time with only one command) ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. 1/ identify the local ranks of the processes by for example following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935518/5239503); then 2/ read the connectivity from a file; and finally 3/ create your communicators (either inter or intra ones, your choice) accordingly. Totally reasonable approach from my standpoint.